# no module found even after installation of any module for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, biopython

I am using VS code and python 3.10.5 with pip 24.0. I am getting error of nomodulefound even after installing. I want to use biopython and sciki-allele. I have created virtual environment too. Your help will be valuable. Thank you!

I tried different solutions which were previously given. like 'pip3 install biopython'. Also I am using windows10

[for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At4Yz.png)

Comment: Could you show the command you are trying, as well as the error you are getting?

Comment: The problem might be that you have not activated the virtual environment in vs-code. You can look at the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for how to use python virtual environments in vs code

Comment: It appears from your image that you have an extra 'e' in allel, try `python -m pip install scikit-allel`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use pip that does not "belong" to your python. Maybe you got confused with python environments.

`which pip` will help you to understand which pip is used.

if you want to make sure it is the one belonging to your current python. Install with `python -m pip install packagename`

As you name vscode: If you are using interactive python (the line-by-line execution of python code), make sure you [select the right kernel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management):

[image]